# Text File of Monthly Temps into Set

Tags: list, python-3.x, file-io, set

I have a .txt of months of one year with daily temperature readings.

I want to take the list created from .readlines(), and separate each month and eliminate any duplicate values (using a set).

This is the text file:

```
January:23,23,23,21,21,23,23,22,22,23,23,23,22,22,22,23,23,23,22,19,22,23,22,22,22,22,22,23,23,23,22
February:23,22,26,26,26,27,27,27,26,26,26,27,27,3,26,26,27,26,26,26,27,26,26,26,26,26,26
March:19,18,18,18,23,21,31,33,33,22,19,18,18,18,4,5,31,33,19,18,19,18,18,18,23,21,31,33,33,22
April:40,17,17,17,19,19,18,19,22,22,19,19,18,19,23,17,19,5,18,19,17,19,19,18,19,22,22,19,19,18
May:1,19,19,18,19,22,22,19,19,18,36,35,22,22,22,19,33,27,6,23,22,22,19,22,23,23,22,22,19,19
June:33,23,19,18,19,22,22,19,19,18,36,35,22,22,19,19,18,22,19,19,8,36,22,19,19,18,36,35,22
July:23,23,23,23,23,33,33,33,22,22,19,19,18,36,35,49,19,19,18,36,35,9,19,19,18,36,35,22
August:18,23,36,35,49,19,19,18,36,35,49,19,19,18,36,35,22,19,19,18,36,35,49,15,19,18,36,35,22
September:18,36,35,49,19,19,18,36,35,49,19,19,18,36,35,22,23,23,18,36,35,49,14,19,19,18,36,35,22
October:18,36,35,49,19,19,18,36,35,49,19,19,18,36,35,22,23,23,22,22,33,22,19,19,19,19,18,36,35,22
November:18,36,35,49,19,19,18,36,35,49,19,19,18,36,35,22,23,23,23,24,22,22,19,18,36,35,49,19,21,11
December:18,36,35,49,19,19,40,23,22,22,23,18,36,35,49,19,19,18,36,18,36,35,12,19,19,18,23,22,22,23
```

This is what I have so far:

```
year_weather = None
months = ['January', 'Feburary', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',
          'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

def open_weather():
    global year_weather
    weather = open('yearly_temperature.txt')
    year_weather = weather.readlines() 
    return year_weather

def month_temp(year_weather, months):
    output = []
    for x in months:
        for y in year_weather:
            output.append(months[x])
            output.append(year_weather[y])
    return output
```

I know I have to create a For loop, which takes each value in months and adds each corresponding value from year_weather to it i.e January from months + the values for that month in year_weather.

But I can't seem to figure it out.

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you can do. We take each line, strip the month and the newline and then split it by commas. Then we convert the list into a set and voila. Also, there is no need to declare the `year_weather` as a global variable.

```
months = ['January', 'Feburary', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',
          'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

def open_weather():
    weather = open('yearly_temperatures.txt')
    year_weather = weather.readlines() 
    return year_weather

def month_temp(year_weather, months):
    output = []
    for i in range(len(months)):
        output.append((months[i], set(year_weather[i].lstrip(months[i] + ":").strip("\n").split(","))))
    return output

yw = open_weather()
print(month_temp(yw, months))
```